# Issues pushing char arrays to stack in java

Tags: java, arrays, stack

Ok, so I'm working on a program that solves a game using depth first search (this is part of a homework assignment). I am storing the board for the game in a 2D char array. As such, I have created a stack to store the various board states:

```
private Stack<char[][]> open = new Stack();
```

I have the following 2 methods:

```
public void dfsearch() {
    open.push(this.board);

    while (!open.isEmpty()) {
        char[][] state = open.pop();
        System.out.println("Popped " + Arrays.deepToString(state) + " from stack");

        if (goal(state)) {
            System.out.println("Goal!");
            break;
        }

        if (!visited(state)) {
            generateChildren(state);
            visited.add(state);
        }
    }
}

private void generateChildren(char[][] state) {
    for (int i=0; i<state.length; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<state.length; j++) {
            char[][] tmp = new char[N][N];
            System.arraycopy(state, 0, tmp, 0, state.length);
            touch(tmp, i, j);
            System.out.println("Pushing " + Arrays.deepToString(tmp) + " to stack");
            open.push(tmp);
            System.out.println("Peeking " + Arrays.deepToString(open.peek()) + " from stack");
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the dfsearch() method is where I'm doing the depth first search and the generateChildren() method is where I'm generating the children nodes to search through.

**Here's my problem:** the arrays aren't being pushed to the stack correctly. To illustrate what I mean, I added some print statements to print what's being pushed and popped from the stack. Within my generateChildren() method it outputs the following:

```
Pushing [[R, R, R], [R, D, D], [D, D, D]] to stack
Pushing [[E, E, E], [R, R, D], [D, D, D]] to stack
Pushing [[E, D, D], [R, R, R], [D, D, D]] to stack
Pushing [[D, D, D], [E, E, R], [R, D, D]] to stack
Pushing [[D, R, D], [D, D, E], [R, R, D]] to stack
Pushing [[D, R, R], [D, R, D], [R, R, R]] to stack
Pushing [[D, R, R], [R, R, D], [E, E, R]] to stack
Pushing [[D, R, R], [R, E, D], [D, D, E]] to stack
Pushing [[D, R, R], [R, E, R], [D, R, D]] to stack
```

To verify what was pushed to the stack, I also added a print method to print the results from peeking at the stack, which results in the following:

```
Peeking [[R, R, R], [R, D, D], [D, D, D]] from stack
Peeking [[E, E, E], [R, R, D], [D, D, D]] from stack
Peeking [[E, D, D], [R, R, R], [D, D, D]] from stack
Peeking [[D, D, D], [E, E, R], [R, D, D]] from stack
Peeking [[D, R, D], [D, D, E], [R, R, D]] from stack
Peeking [[D, R, R], [D, R, D], [R, R, R]] from stack
Peeking [[D, R, R], [R, R, D], [E, E, R]] from stack
Peeking [[D, R, R], [R, E, D], [D, D, E]] from stack
Peeking [[D, R, R], [R, E, R], [D, R, D]] from stack
```

So far so good, right? Well, when I print the results from popping from the stack in my dfsearch() method I get the following:

```
Popped [[D, R, R], [R, E, R], [D, R, D]] from stack
Popped [[D, R, R], [R, E, R], [D, R, D]] from stack
Popped [[D, R, R], [R, E, R], [D, R, D]] from stack
Popped [[D, R, R], [R, E, R], [D, R, D]] from stack
Popped [[D, R, R], [R, E, R], [D, R, D]] from stack
Popped [[D, R, R], [R, E, R], [D, R, D]] from stack
Popped [[D, R, R], [R, E, R], [D, R, D]] from stack
Popped [[D, R, R], [R, E, R], [D, R, D]] from stack
Popped [[D, R, R], [R, E, R], [D, R, D]] from stack
```

As you can see, all the arrays being popped from the stack are equal to the last array pushed to the stack in the generateChildren() method.

Hopefully you were able to follow that. My question is, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: for (int i=0; i<state.length; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<state.length; j++) { is the assumption that the array is NxN?

Comment: Yes, it's an NxN grid. In fact, in my actual implementation (this was taken from one a threw together to test some stuff) I have a variable called N that corresponds to the grid size.

Comment: If the last push does not meet the goal, it will generate children again. It has to meet the goal with the seed state to work. I think you need to fix the recursion. If this fixes your problem let me know to place it as answer

Comment: Hmm... the if(!visited(state)) should stop it from looking at the exact same state twice. Since the board is being modified each time we should be getting a new set of states from generateChildren(), in effect building a tree of all possible states. At least that's how it would work if it could go through all the needed iterations. It stops at 9 iterations because the stack gets populated with 9 identical arrays. As a result we don't ever generate the children for the different states because there are no new states to generate the children for.

Comment: But in the second pop is clean. It doesn't work, it is not visited and generates children. Maybe this is the behavior and the printing is correct

Comment: You are adding to visited after popping. Those arrays will never be in the stack again. What is visited, a set? Did you override equality?

Comment: Visited is simply an ArrayList that stores the visited states. In the visited() method I test if the current state is stored in the arraylist. I'm doing this using Arrays.deepequals() (yes, I know, this is not an efficient way to do this). Unless something is going completely over my head here, I don't think that's related to my stack issue. I've stepped through the code in a debugger and watched the values placed onto the stack and they're all identical. I am 100% positive that the arrays I'm trying to push to the stack are unique, so I know that's not the issue...

Comment: Also, shouldn't the node be set to visited after popping? That places the current state into the list of visited states so it won't be visited again. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I would check the exact wording of deep equals to make sure it does what you expect it does. But the original point remains: the second pop is the last push. If this doesn't work, it will generate children because it's not visited

Comment: Ok, I feel kind of stupid now. I've found the problem. It turns out that the problem was with me using System.ArrayCopy(). When I switched to using my own method for copying the array everything worked fine. I didn't take into account the fact that arraycopy doesn't do a deep copy

Answer (score 0):

To anyone that stumble upon this, it turns out my problem was actually pretty simple. I was using System.arraycopy to copy my array. I didn't take into account the fact that this doesn't do a deep copy, so it was causing issues.